# How to call Resource_name with a String variable?

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I would like to replace the default ImageView with a random drawable file. I'm trying to use a string that will call a **resource_name** in java with a  variable string that changes based on the user's input.

JAVA code

```
String random1 = userinput_1;
String random2 = userinput_2;
String replaceImageView = (random1+"_"+random2);
orignalImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.replaceImageView);
```

Comment: Mike M could you please help apply the logic in those question to mine. I'm lost and have been at this problem for over a week and I'm not seeing how those questions help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the identifier using the name, then use it as you would normally

```
String random1 = userinput_1;
String random2 = userinput_2;
String replaceImageView = (random1+"_"+random2);
int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(replaceImageView, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
orignalImageView.setImageResource(drawableResourceId);
```

Comment: I have tried using drawable ResourceId as an int and a String without any luck. Android studio keeps hightlights the R.drwable.**drawableResourceId) ** as an error. I'm not sure why I'm doing wrong here, Should I be calling the drawable file a different way?

Comment: You don't need "R.drwable.", just "drawableResourceId", you just have to make sure the String replaceImageView matches the resource name exactly.

Comment: That did thanks Alirio